# CSS and selector's

Tags: css, selector

There are six different types of selectors in CSS style rules: type selectors, universal selectors, ID 
selectors, class selectors, pseudo-class selectors, and descendant selectors. Identify and name the 
four different selectors used in the following style rules.

```
#a1, .important { font-style:italic } 
ol span { background-color:aqua } 
a:hover { color:green }
```

I used this site for information.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#simple-selector

The only one i can guess is that
`#a1` is a universal selector?

Could someone please explain this to me? Or could you find me a website that does, i didn't find any sites useful and w3 isn't helping me either

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048 **Although I'm not sure why we are doing your homework for you.**

Comment: this really looks like a homework, please don't post such a question here.

Comment: This is not homework, this is a past paper question for my web tech exam and i'm not asking for you to do it, i'm asking to be pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3 documentation is very verbose and difficult for a beginner, to interpret

try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

specifically, to answer your question:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: no problem. make sure to vote up / accept the answer(s) that answered your question!

Answer (score 1):

The first one is ID selector PLUS class selector for ID "a1" and class ".important".
The second is descendant selector for all spans that are children of ol.
The third is universal selector for all anchor tags on hover state.

Comment: in such cases, better point the OP to a resource that could help them learn things on their own.

Answer (score 0):

```
#a1  - ID selector 
.important    - class selector
ol span  -  universal selector
a:hover - pseudo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this site for learning. It is very good for beginners.

http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web